# CSS Dropdown list without extending background border

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am currently have an issue which I wasn't able to solve myself, so I am turning my issue to you guys and hope that you could help me.

I am trying to create a dropdown list/menu and it works perfect, though the background border extends with the dropdown list, which look like a mess.

So I would like to get your opinion to solve this problem. I have put the code online and have a little demo for the menu with the dropdown list:

**Demo**: http://test.xavizus.eu/test2/
**CSS**: http://codepaste.net/zjyeha

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is with your HTML markup.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for providing the relevant code and a demo, that's really helpful.

Comment: Thank you Jared :)
SidMS - I have identified the problem and it's in my "Menu" id - if you take a look at: http://test.xavizus.eu/test/ that's working well.
So the problem lies in this part:
#menu { 
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#484848;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font:8pt verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
I am not really sure how to do to just ignore this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
#menu { 
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #484848;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font: 8pt verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

That will allow the `ul` submenu to display, but will keep the `#menu` from growing to accommodate it's height.

Comment: Sometimes problems can get solved by simple solution... 
Thank you very much Jared :) - Feel like I am inside a nutshell right now :)

Comment: No problem, glad I can help. Be sure to upvote and mark as the answer if it answers your question. `:)`

Comment: Will do, when I figure that out :D - Found it! :D